# Neovim configure lsp init.vim

Tags: neovim, lsp

How to attach the lsp-client properly? I installed Neovim v0.8.3 and `nvim-lspconfig` manually:

```
$ mkdir ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start
$ git clone https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig.git ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/nvim-lspconfig
```

Then I opened `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, run `:packadd lsp-config` and add the following line to the file:

```
lua require('lspconfig').pylsp.setup{cmd = {"pylsp", "--tcp", "--port", "2087"}}
```

After creating project

```
~/pythonProjects/helloworld$ python3 -m project_cli -y
~/pythonProjects/helloworld$ pipreqs ./    
~/pythonProjects/helloworld$ find | sed 's|[^/]*/|- |g'
.
- setup.py
- README.rst
- helloworld
- - __init__.py
- - __main__.py
- requirements.txt
- tests
- - __init__.py
- - context.py
- - test_main.py
```

I start `nvim helloworld/__main__.py` and run `:LspInfo`:

```
Press q or <Esc> to close this window. Press <Tab> to view server doc.                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                        
Language client log: /home/user/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log                                                                                         
Detected filetype:   python                                                                                                                            

0 client(s) attached to this buffer:                                                                                                                   

Other clients that match the filetype: python                                                                                                          

Config: pyright                                                                                                                                        
 filetypes:         python                                                                                                                             
 root directory:    /home/user/pythonProjects/helloworld                                                                                          
 cmd:               pylsp --tcp --port 2087                                                                                                            
 cmd is executable: true                                                                                                                               
 autostart:         true                                                                                                                               
 custom handlers:                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                            
 Configured servers list: pylsp
```

`pgrep pylsp` returns a process id, that indicates Neovim starts the language server. And there is no `/home/user/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log` created only a empty `/home/user/.local/state/nvim/log`.

Comment: I noticed `root directory Not Found`. What is the current working directory when the file is opened? Does the current working directory or one of its parent contains a `.git` folder or a `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I noticed too, but don't give much attention, because for me it's unclear that this is part of minimal requirements. there is no specific working directory, it gets the working dir of my shell. I just create a test file in my home dir and opened it with `nvim file.py`. Related to your hint I find [this](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/pylsp.lua). It seems I have to created a proper python project?

Comment: If you add a `requirements.txt` file next to your `file.py` does it solve your problem?

Comment: I believe the language server works on projects more than on single files. It could be the origin of the problem.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt please find my edits above. I created a python project and a requirements.txt inside the project but no client attached.

Comment: Do you have client for the server like [nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp) for completion of [null-ls](https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim) for fomating?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Not yet, and it seems that the build-in client does [not support TCP](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11911). They say built-in LSP works through `nc`. you know how to apply this approach for pylsp. Or is `coc.nvim` a client which supports TCP connections?